# How to find and replace certain string pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, string

As a result of text extrapolation from PDF's I need to fix some bugs.
I need to replace every form of strings like these:

```
String example="the sun was shin- ing  and the sky bl- ue";
```

in the form:

```
String fixxed="the sun was shining  and the sky blue";
```

I'm not expert in regular expressions, I tried to do so but it's wrong.

```
String pattern="([\\w])+([\\-])+([\\s])";
String fixxed = text.replaceAll(pattern, "$1");
```

An important specification, I only have to replace the substring if the character before '-' is a letter (not a space and not a number).

Comment: Please check the answers below and let know if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "the sun was shin- ing  and the sky bl- ue";
        example = example.replaceAll("\\-\\s+", "");
        System.out.println(example);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
the sun was shining  and the sky blue
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot an important specification. I only have to replace the substring if the character before '-' is a letter (not a space and not a number).

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the letters before, the letter after and combine them:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "the sun was shin- ing  and the sky bl- ue a - a 1-2 1 - 2";
    String pattern = "(\\w+)-\\s(\\w)";

    String newExample = example.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2");
    System.out.println(newExample);
}
```

#### Output:

```
the sun was shining  and the sky blue a - a 1-2 1 - 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot an important specification. I only have to replace the substring if the character before '-' is a letter (not a space and not a number). The followings examples are not to replace:  a - a  ,   1 - a , 1 - 1

Comment: @Brianzaska The example only replaces if the dash `-` has a letter before it. `(\\w*)-` stands for "any sequence of word letter with any length that has a dash at the end". It ignores other parts of the string that has a dash but no letter before it. The example you posted should work with the solution above.

Comment: if I try with "a - a" it replace the string with "a a", but I don't want to replace it. For instance, the following string must not be replaced "a - a 1-2 1 - 2". Thanks

Comment: @Brianzaska I have updated the post and it should no longer replace `a - a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceAll() method of String to replace a specific set of characters.

According to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)),

> **replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)**
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression
> with the given replacement.

So, for your case you can do it like,

```
 String example = "the sun was shin- ing  and the sky bl- ue";
 System.out.println(example.replaceAll("- ",""));
```

or

```
String example = "the sun was shin- ing  and the sky bl- ue";
System.out.println(example.replaceAll("\\-\\s+",""));
```

Output for both cases will be like below,

```
 the sun was shining  and the sky blue
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot an important specification. I only have to replace the substring if the character before '-' is a letter (not a space and not a number). The followings examples are not to replace: a - a , 1 - a , 1 - 1

Answer (score 0):

To only replace the substring if the character before `-` is a letter (using `\w` to match a word character), you could use a [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert a word character on the left and on the right.

This will replace `bl- ue` to `blue` and also replace `bl- u- es` to `blues`

```
(?<=\w)-\s(?=\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SwtgK0/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/adQByC)

For example

```
String example = "the sun was shin- ing and the sky bl- ue or bl- u- es";
System.out.println(example.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)-\\s(?=\\w)", ""));
```

Output

```
the sun was shining and the sky blue or blues
```

---

If you don't want to change:

```
bl-
ue
```

to

```
blue
```

You could use `\h` to match a horizontal whitespace char instead of using `\s`, which could also match a newline.

```
(?<=\w)-\h(?=\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NcN7PT/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution with any language, even those using diacritics:

```
(\p{L}\p{M}*+)-\h(?=\p{L})
```

Or, with `\h+`, if there can be more than one space between the letter and `-`+letter:

```
(\p{L}\p{M}*+)-\h+(?=\p{L})
```

Replace `\h` with `\s` if there can be a line break between the parts of a torn word.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ByNx5j/1), replace the matches with `$1` replacement backreference that will put the contents of Group 1.

- `(\p{L}\p{M}*+)` - Group 1: any Unicode letter followed with 0 or more diacritics
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\h+` / `\s+` - one or more horizontal / any whitespace chars
- `(?=\p{L})` - a positive lookahead that requires the next char to be any Unicode letter.

See the [Java code](https://ideone.com/09B3pI):

```
String text = "the sun was shin- ing  and the sky bl- ue";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)-\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "$1"));
// => the sun was shining  and the sky blue
```